# How to detect abnormal disconnect in winsock2?

Tags: c++, winsock

For non-blocking sockets, I know that `recv()` will return 0 with no error code if the remote client has gracefully disconnected (assume we are the server). How would you detect abnormal disconnection? Will `recv()` still return 0, or is there some other way to use the API to detect this?

Comment: Look at MSDN for recv(), especially what it returns.  All will be revealed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If connection is physically broken or the other host has shut down without gracefully closing the socket your `recv` will be waiting forever. At the socket level, you can use [`select()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and set timeout for waiting data to be available for reading on the socket.  You'll have this in a loop and if data is available - read it (`recv()`); if `select()` times out, close the socket gracefully and reconnect.

Another solution would be having implemented keep-alives in your protocol. One side is periodically sending keep-alive messages and another side has a timer with a timeout set (adjusted to sending period) and is waiting for them. If timer times out, "waiting" host closes its socket and tries to reconnect.

Comment: Good point - if that is what the OP means by 'abnormal disconnection', he/she could be waiting a long, long time..

Answer (score -2):

Look at MSDN for recv(), especially what it returns. All will be revealed!

Comment: Note that 'abnormal disconnection' <> no disconnection!  If the network cable falls out of the peer and you don't attempt to send any data, (ie you are waiting for data), you could wait forever, as pointed out by @Bojan

Comment: Please review my question more closely; I asked about abnormal disconnection (or non-graceful disconnection). recv() documents it returns 0 during _graceful_ disconnection.

Comment: The server 'going away' is not an abnormal disconnection from the client POV.  WSAECONNRESET, WSAETIMEDOUT or WSAECONNABORTED are abnormal disconnects, as returned by WSAGetLastError() afer recv() has returned with SOCKET_ERROR. A half-connection is not abnormally disconnected.